# Proof by contrapositive for non zero numbers such that if one is rational and the other irrational then the product is irrational.

Tags: alternative-proof, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

I was showing someone an example of a proof where contrapositive is the way to go. Clearly, I cooked up the wrong implication. In any event, now I want to complete the proof regardless. And, do so by showing the contrapositive even though I know invoking a [contradiction](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1511688/783364) is easier in this case. I want to show, let $a \neq 0 \neq b$,
$$
a \not\in \mathbb{Q} \wedge b \in \mathbb{Q} \Rightarrow ab \not\in \mathbb{Q}
$$

Then the contrapositive will be,
$$
ab \in \mathbb{Q} \Rightarrow a \in \mathbb{Q} \vee b \not\in \mathbb{Q}
$$
We start by assuming $ab \in \mathbb{Q}$ then by definition of rationals,
$$
ab = \frac{p}{q}, \quad \gcd(p,q)=1, \quad (p,q) \in \mathbb{Z}^2
$$
I am bit confused from here, I tried,
$$
a = \frac{p}{bq}, \quad b = \frac{p}{aq}
$$
But how does this help me show $a \in \mathbb{Q} \vee b \not\in \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: How is the contrapositive wrong? Could you explain a little more? Maybe write the original statement and then show me the correct contrapositive.

Comment: The contrapositive you have written is correct and $a=b=0$ is not a counterexample.

Comment: "The contrapositive you have written is not correct.", "The contrapositive you have written is correct", guys, I said no contradictions! :D

Answer (score 1):

You assume $ab\in\Bbb Q$ and $b\ne0,$ and want to prove $a \in \mathbb{Q} \vee b \not\in \mathbb{Q},$ i.e.
$$b\in \mathbb{Q}\implies a\in \mathbb{Q}.$$
Simply assume moreover that $b\in \mathbb{Q}$ and write $a=\frac{ab}b.$

Comment: How does $ab \in \mathbb{Q} \Rightarrow b \in \mathbb{Q}$? Why can I just assume it?

Comment: You want to show that "$a\in \mathbb Q\vee b\not\in \mathbb Q$" Annes answer suggests to substitute this by its classically equivalent "If not $b\not\in \mathbb Q$ then $a\in \mathbb Q$".

Comment: Well, I am not sure how to get from $ab \in \mathbb{Q}$ to $b \in \mathbb{Q}$, since $ab \in \mathbb{Q}$ can be made true even when both $a$ and $b$ are irrational. Take $\sqrt{2}\times \sqrt{8}=4$.

Comment: I did nothing more than (very naively!) 1) consider $P\Rightarrow Q$ as equivalent by definition to $Q\lor\neg P$ and apply this to $P=(b\in\Bbb Q)$ and $Q=(a\in\Bbb Q)$; 2) In order to prove $P\Rightarrow Q$, assume $P$ and try to prove $Q$ (like you intended to do in order to prove $ab \in \mathbb{Q} \Rightarrow (a \in \mathbb{Q} \vee b \not\in \mathbb{Q})$).

Comment: I might be missing something subtle here. Our whole thing comes down to proving, $$ab \in \mathbb{Q} \Rightarrow b \in \mathbb{Q} \Rightarrow a \in \mathbb{Q}.$$ We assume $ab \in \mathbb{Q}$ and now have to show some intermediate steps via forward reasoning that $b \in \mathbb{Q}$ then having shown $ab \in \mathbb{Q} \Rightarrow b \in \mathbb{Q}$, the rest $a \in \mathbb{Q}$ follows. What are the explicit-intermediate steps that take us from $ab \in \mathbb{Q}$ to $b \in \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: "Our whole thing comes down to proving"$$ab \in \mathbb{Q} \Rightarrow( b \in \mathbb{Q} \Rightarrow a \in \mathbb{Q}),$$not$$(ab \in \mathbb{Q} \Rightarrow b \in \mathbb{Q}) \Rightarrow a \in \mathbb{Q}.$$So, I assumed $ab \in \mathbb{Q} $ (like you)  and moreover $b \in \mathbb{Q}$ (similarly), and deduced $a\in \mathbb{Q}$ from these 2 assumptions.