# How do you prove a chain of implications?

Tags: proof-writing

$\newcommand{\Ra}{\Rightarrow} \newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}$

We prove $P \Ra R$ by assuming $P$ then showing some middle $Q$, i. e., $P \Ra Q \Ra R$. What if we have to show $A \Ra B \Ra C$. Do we prove this one implication at a time, say, Assume $A$ then show $A \Ra B$, then $B\Ra C$. Or, do we assume $A, A\Ra B$ which is then essentially assume $A, B$ and then show $C$?

This question is inspired by [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4629405/783364). Let $b\neq 0$. We want to show this by contrapositive.
$$
a \not\in \Q \wedge b \in \Q \Ra ab \not\in \Q
$$
Then the contrapositive,
$$
ab \in \Q \Ra a \in \Q \vee b \not\in \Q
$$
Is the same as,
$$
ab \in \Q \Ra b \in \Q \Ra a \in \Q
$$
The answer there assumes $ab \in \Q$. Which makes sense, but then they moreover assume $b\in \Q$. Why? Should there not be some intermediate steps showing that
$$
ab \in \Q \Ra ? \Ra b \in Q. 
$$
What am I missing here?

Comment: As the king told Alice, you begin at the beginning, and go on till you come to the end: then stop.

Comment: Less literally, "We prove P⇒R by assuming P then showing some middle Q, i. e., P⇒Q⇒R" does not seem to make much sense. What is Q? One generally proves an implication such as P⇒R by assuming P and then proving R.

Comment: If Alice wants to prove to Bob that $P\Rightarrow R$ and Bob already agrees that $Q\Rightarrow R$ then Alice shows Bob $P\Rightarrow Q \Rightarrow R$.

Comment: How would one guess that from what you wrote int he question?

Comment: Also, an expression such as A⇒B⇒C is in almost all cases understood to mean the conjunction of A⇒B and B⇒C. If you want to write something like A⇒(B⇒C) or  (A⇒B)⇒C you have to explicitly write the parentheses (the logical operator ⇒ is not associative)

Comment: Well, I was somewhat confused about the partial (right) associativity of the implication but I did try to say this via "We prove $P \Rightarrow R$ by assuming $P$ then showing some middle $Q$"... Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: If Alice wants to tell Bob that A⇒B⇒C and Bob knows that B⇒C then what Alice has to do is to show him that A⇒B, not that A⇒B⇒C (which, as I said, is really bad notation)

Comment: "One generally proves an implication such as $P\Rightarrow R$ by assuming $P$ and then proving $R$." By $Q$, I meant, it is something that is "proving $R$" having assumed $P$.

Comment: In case you require further clarification: [multiple equivalences](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4251447/21813) and [another example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4495116/21813)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose I have three statements $A,B,C$. Then, the following are all logically equivalent (just write out a simple truth table for them all or use whatever rules of logic you know):
\begin{align}
[A\implies (B\text{ or } \neg C)]\equiv [A\implies (C\implies B)]\equiv [(A \text{ and } C)\implies B].
\end{align}
For your question specifically,

- $A$ is the statement that $ab\in \Bbb{Q}$,
- $B$ is the statement that $a\in\Bbb{Q}$,
- $C$ is the statement that $b\in\Bbb{Q}$.

---

Even if you didn't know about the logical equivalences, the following should make sense intuitively. Let's say after writing the contrapositive, we start by assuming $ab\in\Bbb{Q}$. Ok, now we have two cases:

- Case 1: $b\notin\Bbb{Q}$. In this case, the 'or statement' "$a\in\Bbb{Q}$ or $b\notin\Bbb{Q}$" is trivially satisfied.
- Case 2: $b\in\Bbb{Q}$. After some work, you'll end up showing $a\in\Bbb{Q}$, so again, the "or" statement is satisfied.

So, in either case, the "or" statement is satisfied, which completes the proof of the whole implication.